# How would I sum elements in a 2D array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, element

I am trying to to sum values inside a 10 x 10 two dimensional array in **C**. Lets say for example in index[0][0] I have a value of 1. I want to sum up that element and the elements to its immediate right, left, top, and under. So (1 + 0 + 1 ) = 3.

As I move to index[0][1  ] I will now add 4 values given that I know longer am restricted by the corners. for example (0 + 1 + 0 + + 1) = 2 . That is the 0 value at index[0][1 ] and the values in the indexes to its immediate right, left, and bottom given the top is out of its range. I have provided an image blow to help illustrate what I am working with. I tried many things but I am not sure how to mathematically do this in **C language**

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the sum at [0][0] be 2?

Comment: `(1 + 0 + 1 ) = 3` ?? Is that new math under DeVoss?

Comment: yea my bad on that. Just starting kindergarten

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple function using four `if` statements to avoid adding out-of-bounds values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BOARD_SZ  10

int sum_neighborhood(int, int, int [][BOARD_SZ], int, int);

int main(void)
{
    int board[BOARD_SZ][BOARD_SZ] = { { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
                                      { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                                      { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                                      { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                                      { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
                                      { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 } };

    printf("Sum at [0][0] is %d\n",
           sum_neighborhood(0, 0, board, BOARD_SZ, BOARD_SZ));
    printf("Sum at [0][1] is %d\n",
           sum_neighborhood(0, 1, board, BOARD_SZ, BOARD_SZ));
    printf("Sum at [5][3] is %d\n",
           sum_neighborhood(5, 3, board, BOARD_SZ, BOARD_SZ));

    return 0;
}

int sum_neighborhood(int row, int col, int arr[][BOARD_SZ], int rows, int cols)
{
    int sum = arr[row][col];

    if (row - 1 >= 0) {
        sum += arr[row-1][col];
    }
    if (row + 1 < rows) {
        sum += arr[row+1][col];
    }
    if (col - 1 >= 0) {
        sum += arr[row][col-1];
    }
    if (col + 1 < cols) {
        sum += arr[row][col+1];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Program output:

```
Sum at [0][0] is 2
Sum at [0][1] is 2
Sum at [5][3] is 5
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the best answer yet. Now I can grasp how to approach my problem in a simple manner. Appreciate it David!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin-- no premature optimizations here ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
int add(const int **arr, size_t nrows, size_t ncols)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; ++j)
            sum += arr[i][j];

    return sum;
}
```

Use a pair of nested loops to walk the rows and columns.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question.

Comment: As David says, stackptr. It does not address my question. I know how to walk through using for loops. But I want to be able to add an element at a given index and the elements sitting to its immediate left, right, top, and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

One easy approach is to only consider values with valid indices, but iterate over the entire square around a given index `i`, `j`. Thus:

```
typedef struct {
  int ** data;       ///< data in row order
  int rows, columns; ///< size of the data
} Array;

/// arr - pointer to the data
/// i, j  - row and column to add values around
int sum(const Array * arr, int i, int j) {
  int sumVal = 0;
  for (int k = i-1; k <= i+1; k++)
    for (int l = j-1; l < j+1; l++)
      if (k >= 0 && k < arr->rows && l >= 0 && l < arr->columns)
        sumVal += arr->data[k][l];
  return sumVal;
}
```

Then, to find the first largest block:

```
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct {
  int sum, i, j;
} Sum_t;

Sum_t largest(const Array * arr) {
  Sum_t max = {INT_MIN, 0, 0};
  for (int i = 0; i < arr->rows; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr->columns; ++j) {
      int const s = sum(arr, i, j);
      if (s > max.sum) {
        max.sum = s;
        max.i = i;
        max.j = j;
      }
    }
  return max;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Its not exactly formatted to my concern but It will serve as good blueprint as to how I can approach my problem. Thanks Kuba.